# RestApi post request to specific URL

Tags: java, rest, api, post

Im working on integration with some rest API and i need to make calls to their URLS to receive the data.

Im just wondering if its possible to use a REST web-service which will be mapped to that certain URL instead of the local one and later on I will write the client side that will be mapped to these calls.

for example:

```
@Path("/URL")
public class MessageRestService {

@GET
@Path("/{param}")
public Response printMessage(@PathParam("param") String msg) {

    String result = "Restful example : " + msg;

    return Response.status(200).entity(result).build();

    }

}
```

I cant make straight API calls from client side for example using AngularJs because i get this error:

```
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-        Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin  'http://localhost:63342' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP  status code 400.
```

I did find code samples for straight API calls to URLS from java, but it looks messy especially when you have to create it for a lot of API calls:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class Connection {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

          try {

            URL url = new URL("INSERT URL HERE");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)     url.openConnection();

            conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");


        String messageToPost = "POST";

        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        os.write(input.getBytes());
        os.flush();

        conn.connect();



        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                (conn.getInputStream())));

        String output;
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
        }

        conn.disconnect();

      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

      } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

     }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are facing a *same origin policy* issue.

This is because your client-side (web browser) application is fetched from Server-A, while it tries to interact with data on Server-B.

- Server-A is wherever you application is fetched from (before it is displayed to the user on their web browser).
- Server-B is localhost, where your mock service is deployed to

For security reasons, by default, only code originating from Server-B can *talk* to Server-B (over-simplifying a little bit). This is meant to prevent malicious code from Server-A to hijack a legal application from Server-B and trick it into manipulating data on Server-B, behind the user's back.

To overcome this, if a legal application from Server-A needs to talk to Server-B, Server-B must explicitly allow it. For this you need to to implement CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing) - Try googling this, you will find plenty of resources that explain how to do it. https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/ is also a great starting point.

However, as your Server-B/localhost service is just a mock service used during development and test, if your application is simple enough, you may get away with the mock service simply adding the following HTTP headers to all its responses:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Keep-Alive,User-Agent,Content-Type,Accept [enhance with whatever you use in you app]
```

As an alternative solution (during dev/tests only!) you may try forcing the web browser to disregard the *same origin policy* (eg: `--disable-web-security` for Chrome) - but this is dangerous if you do not pay attention to use separate instances of the web browser for your tests and for you regular web browsing.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I will check this and see if it helps